# How can I solve the blank screen after installing Elementary OS Loki 4

Tags: system-installation, display, greeter

I installed elementary Loki as a fresh install on a new hard-drive. (Note I had it on my old drive.)

The install goes perfectly but after installing any software or updating the system when I restart it only goes passed inputting my security key then the screen goes blank (Black).

In short I never get to the login screen

There is nothing on the screen and as I said it was running perfectly on my previous drive.

I checked the ISO with a hash key and it was perfectly fine.

I also downloaded it multiple times.

One thing I did note the file size of the ISO on the website said 1.32 GB

Once the download was complete it was 1.2 GB with every download even via Torrent.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated thanks in advance.

System Specs are indicated in the attached screen-shot

[image: System Specs]

Note in the interim I am running Linux Mint

Kind Regards.